# Loading a table into MYSQL

Tags: mysql

When I run the following code I get an error stating that the file is not found. I am not sure why. I checked the file names and they match.

```
load data local infile '/Users/blah/Desktop/A.csv' 
into table B fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security, MySQL only knows about it's directory structure.  If it were able to read /Users/... then that would be a security gap.

To resolve, you can copy the A.csv into /var/lib/mysql/[Schema Name]/ and then "load data" that file.

Comment: Is there anyway I could import just the first 100 rows?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the file path must be relative to the database **server**.